# How can Lazy Loaded entities be tested using a mock DbContext?

Tags: entity-framework, unit-testing, mocking, dbcontext

I am using the fake DbContext [recommended by Microsoft for unit testing with EF5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn314429.aspx#preEF6).

Everything is working fine, however I am using a "code first" approach, and some of the code under test is relying on lazy loading of related entities.

```
public partial class Entity
{
    public int EntityId { get; set; }
    public string EntityName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<EntityLifeCycle> EntityLifeCycles { get; set; }
    public virtual EntityStatus PreviousStatus { get; set; }
    public virtual EntityStatus CurrentStatus { get; set; }
}
```

Sample of usage:

```
if (entity.EntityLifeCycles.Count() > 0)
{
    ...
}
```

How can I modify my test code (and not the code being tested) to accommodate this?

Researched links for reference:

- [Testing With a Fake DbContext](http://romiller.com/2012/02/14/testing-with-a-fake-dbcontext/)
- [Mocking your Entity Framework data context and testing it in .NET MVC](http://www.nogginbox.co.uk/blog/mocking-entity-framework-data-context)

Comment: Don't try to mock lazy loading. just prepare the mocks your tests need.

Comment: Generally you want to avoid lazy loading concerns in your unit test(s). It is more of an infrastructure concern and you would write an integration test to verify the desired behavior if needed. It is generally provided by the ORM infrastructure. If the lazy loading is not provided by the ORM you may have a unit test to verify for example a code would return an IEnumerable etc. But that doesn't seem to be the case. You get more value by isolating services that performs lazy loading / data access and test the behavior of the code you have implemented.

Comment: @Raj: Thanks for the comment. Because the code depends on lazy loading (at the moment), I think I'll be using an integration test approach. I have repository set up as a service layer to the EF context, but it started to seem like an extra blanket. Then I ran across this talk by Ayende Rahien, ["Breaking Apart Conceptions"](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0tlMTJDKiug), which has me reconsidering the architecture further.